# Need GGTS 3.5.1 for Linux

Tags: linux, ggts

For reasons I can't go into here, I'm in dire need of getting a copy of a Linux x86_64 GGTS release that supports Grails 2.3.  I have found a 3.5.1 release for Windows on this forum but I really need the Linux 3.5.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux 3.5.1 x86_64 GGTS release that supports Grails 2.3 can be uploaded using this link:

[groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.4-linux-gtk-x86_64](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.5.1/dist/e4.4/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

Comment: Dude your awesome.  I tried to construct a similar link by hand based on the Windows link but I must have missed something vital.

Comment: @BrianTompsett unless, of course, the link is a resource which does not easily fit into a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @MikeCaron Then the answer should have been clearer; I have clarified the answer so it is obvious what the purpose of the link is, which should stop it being flagged by other SO readers.